How can I prevent my WebView from causing lag in the parent Composable?
I have the following code:
@Composable
fun WebTest(modifier: Modifier) {
    val url = "https://www.google.com"
    val ctx = LocalContext.current

    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        Text("title", fontSize = 22.sp, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(44.dp))
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(), 
            factory = { WebView(ctx) }, 
            update = {
                it.loadUrl(url)
            }
        )
    }
}

In this case, the "title" Text always show after the WebView was loaded into the AndroidView, but it is supposed to be shown immediately.
If I comment out the code it.loadUrl(url), the "title" Text will never show. 
If I change WebView to FrameLayout, it work fine.
Why the "title" Text cannot be show immediately?

Using WebView in Compose has some drawbacks. You can try out this wrapper: https://github.com/KevinnZou/compose-webview-multiplatform

@tyg I am afraid this library will probably not resolve the initial bottleneck of creating the AndroidView, as it uses AndroidView itself.

The AndroidView invocation is the bottleneck here. Even if you construct the View outside of the composition, there is a significant lag when the View is applied to the AndroidView. This results in a very slow recomposition, where the whole Composable will go blank until all nested Composables were laid out.
However, the LazyColumn is an exception here - as it lazily loads and lays out its children without affecting the recomposition of the parent Composable. This allows the following workaround:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun WebTest(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val url = "https://www.google.com"
    val ctx = LocalContext.current

    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "WebView Demonstration") },
        )
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).fillMaxHeight(),
            userScrollEnabled = false  // to let the AndroidView consume scrolling

        ) {
            item {
                AndroidView(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxSize(),
                    factory = { WebView(ctx) },
                    update = {
                        it.webViewClient = WebViewClient();
                        it.loadUrl(url)
                    }
                )

            }
        }
    }
}

Comparison without / with LazyColumn:
 

this works for me
